# Expo managed project - android permissions Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, expo

I installed Firebase Analytics inside my Expo managed react native project, and when I try to submit my build to the Google Play Console, it says that I don't have "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" permission inside my Manifest file ...

But as the Expo documentation says https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/, I added as follow the permission inside my app.json file :

```json
"permissions": [
      "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
      "android.permission.CAMERA",
      "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID",
      "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    ],
```

And I use `eas build`. What's the problem ? Why can't this permission be added to my final aab file ?

ChatGPT tells me to do that, but I'm not sure at all if it's working or not since I don't find anything about it on the net :(

```js
import { AndroidConfig } from '@expo/config';

export default ({ config }) => {
  config = AndroidConfig.Permissions.withPermissions(config, [
    'INTERNET',
    'ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE',
    'ACCESS_WIFI_STATE',
    'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE',
    'WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE',
    'CAMERA',
    'com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID'
  ]);

  return config;
};
```